# How to configure Mac MAMP so I don't have to 777 folders

Tags: macos, apache, web, localhost, mamp

At the moment I'm working with a git repo, locally so I don't to change any permissions before I push the files.

I'm using MAMP on OSX 10.6.8. I'm sure there must be something that I'm doing wrong. I would like the web pages to be able to write to folders while maintaining 755 permissions on the folders.

NB: MAMP is installed in Applications, but I have the root directory in a folder on my user folder.

Comment: I moved the web root back into the MAMP htdocs and it is now working. The reason I moved it at first was because some commands required sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is user of process running Apache?
You must change user or group to apache process and You will have access to files and
apache process to.

Example:

```
$ ls -ld incomming
drwxrwxr-x 42 john apache 4096 May 20 07:33 incomming
```

This folder onwner is John, and his have full write permmissions. Also this folder is writable by group apache, which is supposed to be apache process group.

Comment: This is likely the correct answer to most people asking the same question, as I have used it on a live server previously.